# Pandas: How to replace the values of the subsequent cell by its first row cell for each distinct element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID   PurGrp
10    N01
10    N02
20    EC01
20    EC02
20    EC03
30    AB01
40    AB01
40    AB04
```

I want to replace `PurGrp` values of each row by its first value for each `ID`. Do the resultant dataframe should look like

```
ID   PurGrp
10    N01
10    N01   <----Replaced by 1st row of ID =10
20    EC01
20    EC01  <----Replaced by 1st row of ID =20
20    EC01  <----Replaced by 1st row of ID =20
30    AB01
40    AB01
40    AB01  <-----Replaced by 1st row of ID = 40
```

There are ways to to do it. One way is as follows:

```
df['PurGrp'] = df['PurGrp'].mask(df['PurGrp'].str.startswith('N'),'N01')
```

The above snippet can be repeated several times eg. for AB01, EC01 etc. But surely that is not a convenient way.

What I am looking for a dynamic way of replacing the values of subsequent rows by first row for each `ID` column.

Comment: Use `df['PurGrp'] = df.groupby('ID')['PurGrp'].transform('first')`

Comment: @jezrael: I am loosing the `ID` column.

Comment: If use `transform` ? It is weird, are you sure? Because `transform` never do it.

Comment: Yes it is giving that. I am using pandas 1.13

Comment: Oh kh...managed it...Forget to use the left side of the `=` sign